# How do I get results from the blocking function?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7

```
import asyncio
import time

def abab():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    return 10000

async def ab():
    while True:
        print(111)
        time.sleep(1)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)


async def main():
    abc = asyncio.create_task(ab())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    a = loop.run_in_executor(None, abab)
    await abc

asyncio.run(main())
```

while print(111) of ab() function

After 10 seconds, I want to get abab result 10000.

abab function must be blocking function. not a async function

this example print like this

0 111 1 111 2 111 3 111 4 111 5 111 6 111 7 111 8 111 9 111 111 111 111...

but i want to print 10000 when return result

0 111 1 111 2 111 3 111 4 111 5 111 6 111 7 111 8 111 9 111 10000 111 111 111...

This is actually an example, but In the actual code, abab is a blocking function and cannot be modified. I can't think of a solution to this. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you await the result of `run_in_executor` from somewhere, you will receive the return value of the blocking function it executed. Since you already use `create_task` to run `ab()` in the background, nothing stops you from just awaiting the call to `run_in_executor` to pick up the result of `abab()`:

```
async def main():
    # spawn ab() in the background
    abc = asyncio.create_task(ab())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # wait for abab() to finish, allowing ab() to run
    abab_result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, abab)
    # print (or otherwise process) the result of abab
    print(abab_result)
    # continue waiting for ab()
    await abc
```

With this change, the output from the program matches the one you requested.